! use in tables appears to not work in @setup, to read js as it appears to require string values
Hopefully the samples are to the point enough to show the issue, when ran.
In a @setup use, we were looking to replace a field with a dynamic value (variable).  While this works in a basic scenario, usage in the @setup block fails with an error as follows.  Is this expected functionality or a bug?
* replace testGenerator 
|   token   |value! |
|   replaceVar  |replacementVar |
|   replaceString   |'replaced String'  |

expression error (replace string values need to be within quotes): js failed:
>>>>
01: replacementVar
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: "replacementVar" is not defined
- <js>.:program(Unnamed:1)

Here is a code sample showing the replacement of the variable working in the single scenario, but failing in the outline and @setup usage.
Feature: scenario outline using a dynamic generator function
Background:
  # setting url
    * url 'https://www.google.com'

    * def replacementVar = 'this was a replaced variable'

    * configure continueOnStepFailure = true

  @setup
  Scenario: setup of data
  # creating json data and casting as string for replacement
    * def testGenerator = [{ name: 'test replaceVar', replaceVar: '<replaceVar>'},{ name: 'test replaceString', replaceVar: '<replaceString>' }]
    * print 'testGenerator-initial-',testGenerator

  # printing current generated data value
    * string testGenerator = testGenerator
    * print 'testGenerator-string-',testGenerator

  # replacing data in generated data
    * replace testGenerator
    | token         | value!            |
    | replaceVar    | replacementVar    |
    | replaceString | 'replaced String' |

  # converting generated data back to json object for use in scenario
    * json testGenerator = testGenerator

  # printing updated generated data value
    * print 'testGenerator-json-',testGenerator

  Scenario Outline: Outline test name: ${name}
  # printing initial name value
    * print 'name-',name
  # printing initial replaceVar value
    * print 'replaceVar-',replaceVar

    Examples:
    | karate.setup().testGenerator |

  Scenario: Scenario test
  # creating json data and casting as string for replacement
    * def testGenerator = [{ name: 'test replaceVar', replaceVar: '<replaceVar>'},{ name: 'test replaceString', replaceVar: '<replaceString>' }]
    * print 'testGenerator-initial-',testGenerator

  # printing current generated data value
    * string testGenerator = testGenerator
    * print 'testGenerator-string-',testGenerator

    # replacing data in generated data
    * replace testGenerator
    | token         | value!            |
    | replaceVar    | replacementVar    |
    | replaceString | 'replaced String' |

  # converting generated data back to json object for use in scenario
    * json testGenerator = testGenerator

  # printing updated generated data value
    * print 'testGenerator-json-',testGenerator


Sorry, the @setup is special, and placeholder or variable substitutions are not at all possible. You can find a detailed explanation of the design here.
The other thing is that the ! suffix convention works only for the Examples table and nowhere else.

I have showed that the ! works in more than just the examples section as stated, by use in the replace table.  I was simply looking for common use throughout.  There is a comment Type Hints: if the Examples column header has a ! appended, each value will be evaluated as a JavaScript data-type (number, boolean, or even in-line JSON) - else it defaults to string. in scenario outline, but nothing that states it is ONLY allowed in this use case and not others, hence the confusion and ask to expand use or clarify when.where ! should be used.
